# Transform Block linking to multiple targets with predicate not working as expected

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

I have a transform block that is linked to an action block based on a predicate.

```
// Blocks
public TransformBlock<Document, Document> DocumentCreationTransformBlock =
    new TransformBlock<Document, Document>(async document => 
    {          
        return await CreateAsync(document); // REST API call that sets document.NewId
    }, 
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {
        BoundedCapacity = 100,
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20
    });

public ActionBlock<Document> SplitPipelineActionBlock = 
    new ActionBlock<Document>(async document => 
    { // implementation obfuscated 
    },
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {
        BoundedCapacity = 100           
    }; 

// Shared block elements      
public DataflowLinkOptions CommonLinkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions {
    PropagateCompletion = true };

// Link mesh
DocumentCreationTransformBlock.LinkTo(SplitPipelineActionBlock, 
    CommonLinkOptions, 
    document => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(document.NewId));

DocumentCreationTransformBlock.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<Document>(), 
    CommonLinkOptions);
```

The transform block tries create a document via a REST API. It should update the `Document` object with a `NewId`. So the LinkTo predicate checks that the returned Document has a NewId.

For any objects that don't meet this criteria, there is a `NullTarget` block to empty the `TransformBlock`.

In my test, I posted 10,100 items to the pipeline and confirmed that all items returned a `NewId` succesfully. However, 130 items are being passed to the `NullTarget`. When I rerun the program over the entire set again, more than 3000 items are being passed to the `NullTarget`. Even items that previously successfully stored a `NewId`.

I suspect there is an issue with the `SplitPipelineActionBlock` `BoundedCapacity` being full, and the `LinkTo` just ignoring the predicate and then passing the item to be processed by the next LinkTo, which is the `NullTarget`.

How can I make it so that all items are given a chance to be sent to the `SplitPipeLineAction` block?

Comment: Why not remove the `BoundedCapacity` for `SplitPipelineActionBlock`?

Comment: This will eventually be run with over 17 million items and I am concerned about out of memory exceptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an item is available from a source block, it will offer it to its links one at a time; if any link does not receive the item, then that item is offered to the next link. There's no distinguishing *why* a link isn't used. Blocks do distinguish "maybe later" replies from "no" replies ([`Postponed` vs `Declined`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library#message-passing)), but in either case, the next link will be attempted for a linked block that can take it *now*.

Your best option to resolve this is to add a predicate to the null block link that is the negative of the predicate for the target block link.

```
Predicate<Document> predicate = document => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(document.NewId);

DocumentCreationTransformBlock.LinkTo(SplitPipelineActionBlock, 
    CommonLinkOptions, 
    predicate);

DocumentCreationTransformBlock.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<Document>(), 
    CommonLinkOptions,
    document => !predicate(document));
```

This way, when `SplitPipelineActionBlock` is full, then the item is offered to the null link, it's rejected due to failing the predicate, and the item stays in the transform block output buffer until `SplitPipelineActionBlock` has room.

Comment: Thank you, that is clear to me now. I confirmed your explanation by logging all predicate results. I could see every item did get checked by the predicate and all returned true. Many must have been giving a `Postponed` reply, then immediately being processed by the null target block (which is unbounded), thus emptying the source block output queue. I implemented your suggested fix which is now working.